# How to customize django loginview

Tags: django

```
path('account/login', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name='main/log_form.html'), name='login'),
path('account/logout/', auth_views.LogoutView.as_view(template_name='main/logout.html'), name='logout'),
```

How to customize django loginView?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this [example](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/auth/customizing/#a-full-example) of the documentation it is shown how custom authentication works in Django. In the same page there is an example on [how to log an user in](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/auth/default/#how-to-log-a-user-in)